# How to set Vim's Local Leader to Backslash?

Tags: vim

This works fine for setting local leader to the minus key:

> :let mapleader = "-"

I can't figure out how to set it to backslash. I've tried the following with no avail:

> :let mapleader = "\"
>
> :let mapleader = "\"
>
> :let mapleader = \

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you want to change the `<LocalLeader>`, you have to use `maplocalleader`, not `mapleader`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easy way is not to set it. When this variable is empty (or set to an empty
string) it  will default  to the backslash.  Be sure to  check the  help ([`:h
mapleader`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapleader)).

It  was  not  working  because  the backslash,  as  the  escape  character  in
double-quoted strings, needs to be escaped with another backslash (`"\\"`).

In the title of  your question you mention a local leader.  If you really want
to set the  leader locally (that is,  for the current buffer) you  may want to
use `maplocalleader`  instead. But  then you'll  need `<LocalLeader>`  in your
maps instead of `<Leader>`.

A final note: the leader is used when defining your maps, and changing it in a
later time won't re-define the maps.

Answer (score 13):

Either escape the backslash or use single quotes:

```
:let mapleader = "\\"
:let mapleader = '\'
```

Answer (score 3):

From the online help:

> To define a mapping which uses the "mapleader" variable, the special
>   string "`<Leader>`" can be used.  It is replaced with the string value
>   of "mapleader". If "mapleader" is not set or empty, a backslash is
>   used instead.

So just set `mapleader` to be empty, and you'll be using backslash by default:

```
:let mapleader = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

The quoting rules for Vimscript strings are documented at `:help expr-string`.

I recommend to prefer single-quoted `'strings'` unless you need to include special characters like `\n`; you'll have to do less escaping (and mistakes!) this way.